# Как сделать выборку MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Имеются две таблицы:
slider_media 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
slider_slides

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как написать select чтобы получить на выходе:

```
slide_id - id из таблицы slider_slides;
desktop_image_url - name из таблицы slider_media;
mobile_image_url - name из таблицы slider_media;
title;
link;
priority;
```

Знаю что что-то с джоинами как-то но не получается что-то.

Очень буду благодарный

Comment: Это что за поля: `slide_id`, `desktop_image_url`, `mobile_image_url`? Из каких таблиц

Comment: Сори, забыл подписать таблицы, slide_id: это из воторого скрина - id
desktop_image_url: это из первого скрина - name

Comment: По какому полю связываются то?

Comment: в поле `desktop_id` вставляется `id` из таблицы `slider_media`
в поле `mobile_id` то же самое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ss.id AS slide_id, sm1.name AS desktop_image_url, sm2.name AS 
mobile_image_url, ss.title, ss.link, ss.priority FROM slider_slider ss
LEFT JOIN slider_media sm1 ON sm1.desktop_id = ss.id
LEFT JOIN slider_media sm2 ON sm1.mobile_id = ss.id
```

Comment: @russell Если проблема решена, ставьте "вопрос решен"

Comment: А что такое `sm1` и `sm2` ?  `ss` я так понимаю `slider_slides` а `sm` это `slider_media`

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря вашему примеру разобрался, работаает

Comment: `sm1`, `sm2`, `ss` - это алиасы таблиц